# how modify header with Charles Rewrite tool and regex?

Tags: regex, charles-proxy

I need to modify a specific header using regex because the information on certain devices is random, so using regex I could make the rewrite fit for any situation.

i have an header called x-mobile with this values:

`MARCA=samsung,MODELO=SM-G930F`

Values always need to be replaced by the following

`MARCA=iPhone,MODELO=iPhone11`

how make this with regex on Charles Rewrite Proxy?

i already tried MARCA=[\s\S] but without sucess

see on the screen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp3R2.png)

Comment: As for the regex, it can look either like `MARCA=[^,]*`, and use `MARCA=iPhone` in the replacement part. The r

Comment: (?<=MODELO=)[^,]+ solved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=MODELO=)[^,]+
```

*Details*

- `(?<=MODELO=)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `MODELO=` string
- `[^,]+` - one or more chars other than `,`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M5FKgO/1).